# Why is this query succeeding and failing in prolog?

Tags: prolog

In my prolog program, it succeeds in finding who ruled when King Edward VIII was born, but for some reason also fails.  Here is a small chunk of my code:

```
reigned('Queen Victoria', 1819, 1901).
reigned('King Edward VII', 1901, 1910).
reigned('Queen Elizabeth II', 1952, 2013).
born('King George V', 1865).
born('King Edward VIII', 1894).
born('King George VI', 1895).
born('Prince Henry', 1984).

regentWhenBorn(X, Y) :- reigned(X, Begin, End), born(Y, Born), 
                        Begin =< Born, Born =< End.
```

This is what prolog displays:

```
?- regentWhenBorn(Who, 'King Edward VIII').
Who = 'Queen Victoria' ;
false.
```

or for a different person..

```
?- regentWhenBorn(Who, 'Prince Henry').
Who = 'Queen Elizabeth II' ;
Who = 'Queen Elizabeth II'.
```

What is causing this?

Comment: the code is good; you probably have some clauses duplicated somewhere. Make a clean source file and try again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a variable (in this case Who), it assumes all the possible values (in this case 'Queen Victoria','King Edward VII' and 'Queen Elizabeth II') and it tries all of them to find a true. So, if it finds true for the last then it does not show false (your first case), otherwise it displays the result and keep looking (because there can be multiple results) and when it is not able to find any, it displays false.